# Will microsoft force Windows 8.1 users to upgrade to Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade

So Microsoft has forced Windows 7 users to upgrade to Windows 10. Will they plan to force Windows 8.1 (and 8) to upgrade to Windows 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upgrade is necessary because Windows 7 reached the end of it's Mainstream support life, meaning it no longer receives security patches. (Unless you're a corporation willing to pay for extended support, it's expensive)

Windows 8.1 reaches end of it's support life on January 10, 2023, 
After which it will be in the same situation as Windows 7

source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/18581/lifecycle-faq-windows-products

Comment: But it said in a news article and on microsoft page, that it already reached end of life.

Comment: It reached end of mainstream support in 2018, so it will never receive any feature updates, only security. It will become totally unsupported, not even security updates, in 2023 [going the same way as XP, Vista & Win7]

Answer (score 1):

You are not forced to do anything. When the big Full Screen Windows 7 warning comes up, it can be permanently dismissed (small type, lower left). It will still run. Vista still runs, Windows 2000 still runs and so on.

But if security, and modern software is of any use to you, then you will upgrade for that reason (as many of us did) but because we wished to.

I recommend you upgrade . But you are not forced to.  I have all the above running as virtual machines and they are working fine.

You should still be able to find and install GWX Control Panel to stop Windows 10 from trying to update.

Comment: There were many cases of W7 being upgraded without user consent and caused data loss, litigation ensued due to this.

Comment: During the time this was happening our good friend Steve Gibson created this software to ensure unintended upgrade did not happen to anyone who used it>>>>https://www.grc.com/never10.htm

Answer (score 0):

> Will Microsoft force Windows 8.1 users to upgrade to Windows 10?
>
> ---
>
> So Microsoft has forced Windows 7 users to upgrade to Windows 10.

Microsoft *forces* noone to upgrade. It just simply do suspend the update development and support of the respective operation systems.

You can use Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 until the end of time if you want to, equal to Windows Vista, Windows 98 or MS-DOS etc., where the support had ended a long time ago but users are still be able to *use* these systems.

If this would a be recommended thing to do (to keep on not updated systems), with regard to hacking and virus attacks etc., is a different topic.

So the answer to your question is simply as: No.